# What GET Request Endpoint should I Use to Get all groups for User( token passed) in Keycloak

Tags: reactjs, api, keycloak

I am trying to get all user groups in keycloak API.
But I do know know what API Should I use?

```
Server Version  18.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

{{keycloak_url}}/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users/{{userId}}/groups

documentation in here at "GET /{realm}/users/{id}/groups" section

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/

Demo for this by steps

1. preparation for this steps

Realm : **test**

keycloak_url: **localhost:8180/auth**

User: **admin and user1**

user1's groups : **CI-CD and developer** <- I will get this information

1.a  Assign "**manage-users**" role into Admin user
[image]

1.b Assign longer **access token lifespan** with 1 hour
[image]

2. Get Realm's admin access token and save it

2.1 file this setting in **Tests** tab of Postman

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]
2.2 Call get token with 4 parameters
[image]
the status should be return 200 OK of API call
the access token should be assign token variable

3. Get user list and remember the specific user's ID
   [image]
   user ID is **a0d17c80-a7b7-43e2-a62e-5bcb14e82502** in my test
   the Authorization should be select Bearer Token and use 2.2's variable
4. Get its group information
   using 3.'s user id

[image]
the Authorization should be select Bearer Token and use 2.2's variable
Finally I got user's groups information.

Comment: thank you but i m getting
"error": "unknown_error"

Comment: What kind of error and how to get that error?
This is step #1 Get master's access token, #2 get user list, #3 get group list for specific user. I will update my answer step by step.

Comment: @wedsds2, I updated my steps can you try it?

Comment: I am still getting 
"error": "unknown_error"
Error Code: 403

Comment: @wedsds2, which step? at 3 or at 4 of my step. 403 means you have that token not allow to access the API call. How to reproduce your 403 error? can you shows me step by step in your question?